# SQL Conditional CONSTRAINT FILTER

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, filtering, sql-server-express

I don't want to allow duplicates in a table based on the following criteria

For example:
I have

```
ID  Number  AdditionalID
1   458     1234 <-- 458 must be  allow
2   458     1234 <-- 458 must be allow
3   458     123456 <-- 458 must not be allowed because additionalID is different
```

4, 459 ,123456 <- this must be allowed.(the correct one )

Comment: How come 458 is allowed for id 1 and id 2 but not for id 3?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: SQL EXPRESS 2014

Comment: @jarlh ID is simple primary key: this will always be increment by 1 ( i do not care about that) the 458 can be there multiple times while  additionalID is the same ,IF the incoming Number is 458 and the AdditionalID IS Different then must be dropped

Comment: If 458 must always be matched to 1234, why is that not stored as a *single* fact in a *single* row in some other table and then one of those columns dropped from this table? It's possible to implement this constraint but it's not needed if you normalize your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to approach this problem is to *normalize* your data. At the moment, you're storing the *same*, single fact *multiple* times. So I would move this relationship between `Number` and `AdditionalID` into a separate table<sup>1</sup> and drop `AdditionalID` from the current table.

But if you insist on not changing the structure, we can accomplish this with an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views):

```
create table dbo.T (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    Number int not null,
    AdditionalID int not null
)
go
create view dbo.DRI_T
with schemabinding
as
    select
        Number,
        AdditionalID,
        COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    from
        dbo.T
    group by Number,AdditionalID
go
create unique clustered index IX_DRI_T_UniqueAdditionalIDPerNumber on dbo.DRI_T (Number)
go
insert into T(Number,AdditionalID) values
(458,1234),
(458,1234)
go
insert into T(Number,AdditionalID) values
(458,123456) --<-- This insert fails
go
insert into T(Number,AdditionalID) values
(459 ,123456)
```

How does this work? We create a view the will contain one row per unique combination of `Number` and `AdditionalID` columns. But then we declare that the key for this view is *just* the `Number` column. Meaning, effectively, that we only actually allow one such combination to be stored for each `Number` value.

---

<sup>1</sup>In that separate table, `Number` would be the primary key and so of course only one `AdditionalID` could be associated with each `Number`. In fact it closely resembles the indexed view presented here except it doesn't need the `Cnt` column, which is only required here because it's a requirement to be allowed to `GROUP BY` in an indexed view.

Comment: i could not change the Structure of the table but the indexed view was very good solution! THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the full solution of how "Additional id" has allowed numbers there might be couple solutions.

**1. Foreing key**

If possible using foreign key here might be the best solution.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AdditionalID) REFERENCES AllowedAdditionalId(AdditionalID);
```

**2. Constaint check with function**

```
create function dbo.CheckFunction()
returns int
as begin
    return (select 1)
end

alter table YourTable
add constraint chk_CheckFunction
check (dbo.CheckFunction() = 1)
```

Comment: i think i understand your solution with the 2nd example. i thought will be a way doing this without a function.. let me try it..

Comment: Just for reference i have go with Option 2, inside the function i do a quick search and return an integer indicates if will fail or accept it.

Comment: Going the function approach means that you need to (potentially) scan the entire table every time. And it's not infrequent to encounter functions that fail to anticipate complex insert/update/delete activities. I'd favour a declarative approach over one that "tricks" multi-row behaviour into a check constraint.

Comment: @damien_the_unbeliever. But how view dose not affect perfomance? Every time a new row coming in how the view trigger it? Will this be auto trigger somehow? and check the constraint on that time the row coming in?

Comment: @user2160275 - an indexed view is maintained, behind the scenes, with a mechanism very similar to triggers. Except you don't have to write them yourself. Many of the restrictions on what you can do in an indexed view exist precisely because of this trigger like mechanism and, in turn, are there to minimize the performance penalty imposed by the system. I.e. they target only the row(s) affected by any particular DML statement, not the whole table.

Comment: @damien_the_unbeliever that's interesting.i will test and try implement it and come back on Wednesday  to let you know. Very useful of what you said.

Comment: I do agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever that writing check function needs to be done with some thought. If possible to implement his proposal, it might be better.